# Максимальный элемент конвертируемого массива

Tags: c#

```
    static void Main()
    {

        string s = Console.ReadLine();
        int[] massint = new int[s.Length];
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < massint.Length; i++)
            {
                Convert.ToInt32(s);
                Console.WriteLine(massint + "  " + massint[i]);

            }

        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ошибка - неправильный символ");
        }
        int max = c[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < massint.Length; i++)
        {
            if (massint[i] > max)
            {
                max = massint[i];

            }

        }

       Console.WriteLine("MAX = " + max);
       Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

По какой причине не меняет своё значение max?

Как мы можем увидеть,после прогона конвертации каждый индекс будет соответствовать своему значению.Но max упрямо не хочет принимать в себя нулевой элемент массива massint.Вместо этого всегда получается 0(или,как я понял default(int)).В max мы пытаемся реализовать классический максимальный элемент массива,точно так же massint.Max() выводит 0.

Comment: Код не содержит ни одного присвоения `massint[i]`.

Comment: ну а где вы пишете значения в массив?

Comment: 1. Ваш код не компилится (с[0]). 2. Вы не меняете элементы массива в первом цикле и они не выводятся на консоль. 3. Так как массив содержит нулевые значения, то макс=0.

Comment: Извините,забыл внизу сменить c на massint, 

Там будет int max = massint[0];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Без LINQ**

```
static void Main()
{
    var s = Console.ReadLine();
    var massint = new int[s.Length];

    try
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < massint.Length; i++)
        {
            massint[i] = int.Parse(s[i].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(massint[i]);
        }
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ошибка - неправильный символ");
    }

    var max = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < massint.Length; i++)
    {
        if (massint[i] > max)
        {
            max = massint[i];
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("MAX = " + max);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**LINQ**

```
static void Main()
{
    var s = Console.ReadLine() ?? "";
    try
    {
        var array = s.ToCharArray().Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).ToArray();
        if (array.Length > 0)
        {
            var max = array.Max();
            Console.WriteLine("MAX = " + max);
        }
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ошибка - неправильный символ");
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: А без LINQ это есть возможность сделать?Задача - ввести строку,преобразовать  её в массив чисел(если в ней есть значения,которые можно преобразовать в числа) и вывести максимальный элемент.Алгоритм вроде проще,но у меня не выводится только максимальный элемент.

Comment: @Lorchel Добавил пример без LINQ

Comment: Спасибо,с int.Parse с параметрами s[i].ToString() это то,что нужно.Поясните немного,почему с ToString то сработало?

Comment: @Lorchel int.Parse требует на вход строку, для char перегрузки метода нет.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, это можно было бы сделать проще.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace MaxDigitInString
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "12345A678";
            List<int> lst = new List<int>();

            foreach ( char c in s )
            {
                if (char.IsDigit(c)) lst.Add(c - '0');
            }

            Console.WriteLine( "Maximum is {0}", lst.Max() );
        }
    }
}
```

Вот более содержательная демонстрационная программа

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace AirTrafficControl
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s;

            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter a string of digits (Enter - exit): ");
                s = Console.ReadLine();

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)) break;

                List<int> lst = new List<int>();

                foreach (char c in s)
                {
                    if (char.IsDigit(c)) lst.Add(c - '0');
                }

                if (lst.Count != 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The maximum digit in the string is {0}", lst.Max());
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The string does not contain digits");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        Ъ
    Ъ
Ъ
```

Comment: А я сломал! https://ideone.com/Z5S43e

Comment: @Qwertiy: Это у вас такие цифры? о_О

Comment: Это [единицы из разных языков](http://unicode-table.com/ru/search/?q=%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD).

Comment: @Qwertiy Я думаю, что задача автора вопроса - работать с цифрами ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего наверное так:

```
Console.ReadLine().Select(c => Convert.ToInt32(c)).Max();
```

Если надо пропускать плохие значения, то

```
Console.ReadLine().Where(char.IsDigit).Select(c => Convert.ToInt32(c)).Max();
```

Comment: 1. int.Parse с char не работает :(

Comment: @pavelip: Упс. Сейчас поправлю.

Comment: 2. на пустой строке вылетит Max()

Comment: @pavelip: А это пускай, ТС всё равно не сказал, что делать в этом случае.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int[] massint = new int[s.Length];
> ```

Создали массив из всех нулей.

> ```
> Convert.ToInt32(s);
> ```

Сконвертировали всю строку в число несколько раз в цикле, но никуда не сохранили.

Собственно и всё. Максимум из нулей равен нулю.